# How to create an XCB image with width and height different from the connected window?

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib, xcb

I'm working with X11's XCB api.

When I try to create a window and make an `xcb_image_t` struct with `xcb_image_create_native`, it returns `NULL` unless the pixel array I allocate is the exact same size as the pixel array for the window I created.

Below is the smallest example I could put together. If I change all the instances of "width" and "height" to be equal to "window_width" and "window_height", the program runs perfectly, However, if I change "width and height" to anything else, `xcb_image_create_native` returns `NULL`.

I'm compiling on gcc and linking with `-lxcb -lxcb-image` .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#include <xcb/xcb_image.h>

int main(void)
{
    
    // Just setting up the window
    int window_width = 480;
    int window_height = 480;
    xcb_connection_t *c = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
    xcb_screen_t *screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xcb_get_setup(c)).data;
    xcb_drawable_t window = screen->root;
    
    xcb_gcontext_t gcontext = xcb_generate_id(c);

    uint32_t gc_values[] = { screen->black_pixel, 1};
    uint32_t gc_mask = XCB_GC_FOREGROUND | XCB_GC_GRAPHICS_EXPOSURES;
    xcb_create_gc(c,
            gcontext,
            window,
            gc_mask,
            gc_values);

    window = xcb_generate_id(c);
    uint32_t window_values[] = { screen->white_pixel, XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE };
    uint32_t window_mask = XCB_CW_BACK_PIXEL | XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK;

    xcb_create_window(c,
            XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT,
            window,
            screen->root,
            0,
            0,
            window_width,
            window_height,
            10,
            XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT,
            screen->root_visual,
            window_mask,
            window_values);
    
    xcb_map_window(c, window);
    
    int byte_depth = screen->root_depth/8;
    int width = 50;
    int height = 50;
    int bytes = byte_depth * width * height;
    
    // The part that messes up.
    void *base = malloc(bytes);
    uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *)base;

    // This function always returns NULL unless width & height are the same as window_width & window height
    xcb_image_t *image = xcb_image_create_native(c,
                            width,
                            height,
                            XCB_IMAGE_FORMAT_XY_PIXMAP,
                            screen->root_depth,
                            base,
                            bytes,
                            data);
    if (!image)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "No image\n");
    }
    else
    {
        xcb_image_put(c,
                window,
                gcontext,
                image,
                0, 0,
                0);
    }
    sleep(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Is making a XCB image with a different size than the window even possible? And if so, what am I doing wrong?

I also tried finding out what was going wrong by looking at the source code for xcb_image.c, and though I've been able to figure out the basics of what's happening, I don't understand it enough to find out how it works this way.

https://opensource.apple.com/source/X11libs/X11libs-60/xcb-util/xcb-util-0.3.6/image/xcb_image.c.auto.html
https://code.woboq.org/qt5/include/xcb/xcb_image.h.html

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are allocating enough bytes? Very typically in an image library, the beginning of scanlines must be aligned to a 32bit boundary. That means that if the length (in bytes) of a scanline is not divisible by 4, you need to add padding.

Looking at the xcb [source code](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xcb/util-image/tree/image/xcb_image.c), it looks like xcb_image needs enough space into interleave the pixels into one bit per scanline, and then add padding for correct alignment.

This makes the size calculations a little bit complicated, but it results in a 24-bit 480x480 image needing no padding, and an 24 bit image of 50x50 needing a total of 2100 bytes of padding.

Luckily to avoid all this, you can let xcb allocate the correct size for image data. Just call `xcb_image_create_native` with `base=NULL`, `bytes=0` and `data=NULL`. You may then find a pointer to the allocated image data in `image->data`

Don't forget to call `xcb_image_destroy(image)` when you are finished. This will `free` both `image->data` and `image`